# PATH question on my last linux midterm that I need someone to explain

Tags: linux, path

If `/bin/foo` is a program that output hi and `/usr/bin/foo` is a program that outputs hello what would be the output on your screen of this three command sequence:

```
PATH=/bin/foo:/usr/bin/foo:/usr ; cd /bin ; foo
```

The answer should be hi

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. You should probably use another site on the [Stack Exchange network](https://stackexchange.com/sites) for this question. Also see [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/linux+path.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The content of `PATH` should be a ':' separated list of directories, not paths directly to executables. Based on the rest of the question I assume the command sequence was meant to be `PATH=/bin:/usr/bin:/usr ; cd /bin ; foo` rather than `PATH=/bin/foo:/usr/bin/foo:/usr ; cd /bin ; foo`.

If so, the output would be "hi" because of the order of the directories in `PATH`.

When the command `foo` is executed the system checks each of the directories in the `PATH` variable for an executable by that name and executes the first one it finds. Since the directories in order are;

```
/bin
/usr/bin
/usr
```

the executables it will look for are

```
/bin/foo
/usr/bin/foo
/usr/foo
```

From your description we know that `/bin/foo` is a program that outputs "hi" so the first executable it looks for is found, run, and outputs "hi".

The `cd /bin` is a bit of a red herring because the working-directory isn't searched when trying to resolve a command to an executable (unless it happens to be in the `PATH`, in which case it would have been searched regardless).